# someone I did not know but whom would soon become - why is it "whom"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> In the summer of 2001, after 15 years of developing graphical user interfaces and graphics-intensive applications, I read a best-selling book about implementing web applications by someone I did not know—Jason Hunter—but **whom**, unbeknownst to me, would soon become a good friend on the No Fluff Just Stuff (NFJS) tour.

Why is **whom** used in that sentence instead of **who**?

Comment: Seems like an error or a typo.

Comment: It's a mistake of some sort, and you can ignore it. It might be a typo, it might be a [hypercorrection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection), or it might be a WP error--the sort of thing that happens when you revise word-processor text as you go with cuts-and-pastes.

Comment: I would bet money on it being a hypercorrection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ". . . but **whom**, unbeknownst to me, would soon become a good friend on the No Fluff Just Stuff (NFJS) tour."

It's possible that a **Dialect B** speaker got misled by the parenthetical expression "unbeknownst to me", and so, didn't realize that the ***"whom"*** is the subject of the relative clause itself.

Most of us are taught in school and textbooks to use **Dialect A** whenever selecting the case of the relative pronoun for a subject of an embedded content clause. For example:

- 1) *those(i) **who**(i) he thought [ __(i) were guilty ]* -- Dialect A

Notice that the gap has the meaning of "they", which is nominative case, because it is the subject of the embedded content clause ("__(i) were guilty"). And so, the relative pronoun chosen is ***"who"***.

But **Dialect B** speakers have different rules, and they choose the accusative ***"whom"*** as the relative pronoun in this type of situation:

- 2) *those(i) **whom**(i) he thought [ __(i) were guilty ]* -- Dialect B

In your example, the parenthetical expression "unbeknownst to me" might have misled a **Dialect B** speaker into thinking that the relative pronoun was not the subject of the relative clause. That is, he might have thought, erroneously, that your example was similar to #2.

In conclusion: for your original example, it would be considered to be unacceptable in today's standard English--unacceptable for both Dialect A and Dialect B speakers. That is, it is ungrammatical.

For related info, there's the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL), part "(e) Subject of an embedded content clause" within section "16.2.3 *Who* and *whom*", pages 466-7. Especially relevant is footnote 62 on page 467.